# What parts of the trace count for the feedline impedance in antenna design?

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, pcb-antenna

I'm trying to incorporate a ceramic chip antenna in a wearable device due to its low footprint and affordability. After reading the datasheet countless times and YouTube tutorials I'm still not 100% sure on how to make the perfect feedline.

I have used various impedance calculators and obtained the required values for track width and GND clearance, for a co-planar waveguide (this type of "trace" is suggested by the datasheet). My questions are:

- Where does the RF feedline start at? The datasheet says it needs to have 50 Ohm. Does the impedance start counting right after the RF front-end pad up to the ceramic chip or from the pi-network circuit to the chip?
- If the feedline comes from the RF front-end through a thin pad then a thin track is needed to connect to the thin pad. In this case, it will be way thinner than the feedline I computed. Through this approach, I obtained a track with at first 0.2mm (7.9 mil) and then it increases its width up to 1.06mm (41.7 mil; as computed for the 50 Ohm impedance). I'm not sure about this because I assume the thin portion has way higher impedance than the thicker portion that was computed for 50 Ohm. Won't this wdith transition add up (like resistors in series) to the overall feedline resistance?
- If the previous point is true, I had the idea of, instead, computing the feedline parameters by fixing the variables Impedance = 50 Ohm and Track Width = 0.2 mm (so has to prevent width changes), but then it results in a required clearance of 0.07 mm (2.8 mil) which seems to be too low for most manufacturer.

How would you explain / solve this? Should I just go with my current design and hope it works?

[image: Computed parameters for co-planar feedline]

[image: Antenna traces + co-planar feedline]

Thanks!!

EDIT:

After checking everything mentioned, I would just like to know if the transition to the "antenna region" will be problematic (i.e. will it lead to wave reflections?) on the last picture.

Updated feedline parameters:

[image: Updated feedline parameters]

Width transition from RF front end to antenna feedline (way better now):

[image: Width transition from RF front end to antenna feedline]

Width transition from antenna feedline to "antenna region" (it still feels like a big transition, so this is where I'm not sure whether it's OK):

[image: Width transition from antenna feedline to "antenna region"]

Antenna's datasheet (they also seem to have a non-negligible width transition):

[image]

Comment: Consider the board thickness. Make this a four-layer board and all your troubles will disappear, most likely.

Comment: @Hearth I'm sorry but I don't see how increasing the number of layers would solve my specific problem. The board thickness is 1.2 mm (47.2 mil) which was considered in the calculations

Comment: The thickness that matters is the thickness between the controlled-impedance trace and the ground plane beneath it. If you have a four-layer board, and put a ground plane on layer 2, you can massively reduce the trace width needed.

Comment: Also, if you're using a regular CPW, add a ground plane beneath it for a GCPW. That also gets you smaller trace width, and is more predictable than having traces carrying signals underneath it.

Comment: @Hearth when you say “layer 2”, do you mean the layer right below the upper one? Because on this 2-layer board the one bellow is basically a GND plane. In this case, it would be the same I guess

Comment: You forgot to mention operating frequency and lengths of tracks that are not 50 ohm.

Comment: @Andyaka the frequency is 2.4 Ghz (BT and WiFi).

Comment: @AfonsoFerreira no, it's *not* the same! As Hearth explained, if you have 4 copper layers instead of 2 in a board, then the next layer from the top layer is closer. And that changes the geometry of your 50Ω traces for the smaller, and the signal properties for the better. And, you say, the bottom is "practically" a ground plane: that won't do! it needs to be a continuous ground plane (or very low impedance ground referenced). In any case, you must *not* have any gaps in that plane – and you're literally running a trace through that, so that's where you build a mismatch and an unintended slot…

Comment: Device operation alone is hopeless without a solid ground plane underneath it; surrounding components are spaghetti flapping in the wind around the coat-hanger antenna.  A solid ground plane is required to support the antenna and keep transmissions out of your surrounding circuit.

Comment: @AfonsoFerreira … slot antenna. So, yeah, no. Four layers makes a *huge* difference here! Not only can you put your ground plane a fraction of a millimeter below your top signal layer, you can also keep it completely undisturbed, because further signals can be carried on the other two planes.

Comment: So you guys are basically saying I should have an extra layer in between that is completely filled with ground (no components or gaps) which is close to the upper layer in order to stabilize the signal of the RF parts? In this case, I guess it would be ok to still have the vias carrying the signals to the layer which I currently have as the lower layer (with components)

Comment: @AfonsoFerreira Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. You can still have vias, just be careful to maintain ground plane integrity. You'll want via stitching along your controlled-impedance trace; blind vias will help here if they're an option, but they're probably too expensive.

Comment: As a bonus, since they don't make three-layer boards you'll have an entire extra layer to work with, which might reduce the number of vias you need to use in the first place.

Comment: I just edited the original question according to your suggestions. Do you think the width transition from the feedline to the "antenna region" will be problematic (last 2 pictures)? Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help guys. I have updated the design. Apparently, as you suggested, switching from 2 to 4 layers, allow to make the H parameter (thickness in the co-planar waveguide w/ GND plane) considerably smaller simply because, whilst the original total PCB thickness is maintained, the GND plane is now closer to the upper layer (0.1 mm instead of 1.2 mm / 3.93 mil instead of 47.24 mil). Consequently, this influences the calculus of the other feedline parameters (W and S), allowing to use thinner tracks and maintaining the 50 Ohm target impedance.

I have attached images of the resulting changes.

[image: Calculus of new feedline parameters]

[image: Resulting feedline in PCB (upper layer)]

[image: 1st (upper) and 2nd layer (GND plane)]

Comment: Double check the dielectric constant of your manufacturer's prepreg too. It varies a *lot*. (so much, in fact, that you'll need to be able to accept significant variations from the quoted number, too--but it's not going to kill anyone if it's 45 Ω instead of 50.)